# cosmosdb bulkdelete without partitionkey

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Am trying to do a queried document bulk delete using storedprocedure on cosmosdb collection. I have used sample code from here .

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js

When I try to execute the query, am forced to provide a partition key which I do not know. I want to execute a fan out delete query based on query criteria which do not include the partition key. What are other ways I can try and delete documents in bulk from a cosmosdb collection ?

Answer (score 0):

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a
>   single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the
>   documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned,
>   then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a
>   single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then
>   include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the
>   transaction must run under.

You could refer to the description above which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions).

Surely, if your collection has been partitioned, you also need to offer partition key when you operate the collections or documents in it. More details from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data).

So, base on your situation that you do not know the partition key, I suggest you set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to `true` in the `FeedOptions` when executing deletion.(has performance bottleneck)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Right now we are setting 'EnableCrossPartitionQuery='True' in options as below when we are calling from Python. It still shows the error. `pydocumentdb.errors.HTTPFailure: Status code: 400
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.`

Comment: Does this make sense? Am I missing something in the way am making the stored procedure call?